# If $\mu_T = pq$ non-trivially, is $\mathrm{Ker}\: q(T)$ the only $T$-invariant complement to $\mathrm{Ker}\:p(T)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

### Context

Some time ago, I found out that the minimal polynomial gives us a nice way to decompose a finite dimensional vector space $V$ into a direct sum of invariant subspaces:

**Lemma** Let $V$ finite dimensional, $T\in \mathrm{End}\: V$.  If the minimal polynomial $\mu_T$ decomposes into coprime, non-constant factors $p, q\in K[X]$, we have the decomposition $$
  V \simeq \mathrm{Ker}\:p(T) \oplus \mathrm{Ker}\:q(T)
$$
where $P:=\mathrm{Ker}\:p(T)$ and $Q := \mathrm{Ker}\:q(T)$ are $T$-invariant subspaces.  Furthermore, the restrictions satisfy $\mu_{T\vert_P} = p$ and $\mu_{T\vert_Q} = q$.

*Proof* omitted.  (*If you insist, have a look at theorem 5 of [this unfinished attempt at a blog post](http://agdsn.me/~lukasjuhrich/locally_confused/blog/the-jordan-decomposition-revisited/#THM5).*)

In particular, this can be used to prove the following:

**Theorem** The minimal polynomial has distinct irreducible factors if and only if every invariant space admits a complement.

Which nicely generalizes the case where we have an algebraically closed field.

### Add a scalar product

If, however, we have an euclidean ℝ-vector space $(V, \langle -, - \rangle)$, and demand from $T$ to be orthogonal, we find out that $(\mathrm{Ker}\: p(T))^\perp = \mathrm{Im}\:(p(T^\dagger))$, and since (polynomials in) $T$ and $T^\dagger$ commute, the kernel we began with as well as its complement are $T$-invariant subspaces.  However, the above lemma gives us $\mathrm{Ker}\:q(T)$ as a different candidate for a $T$-invariant complement – but says nothing about orthogonality!  Do both describe the same space?

### Question

Let $T\in O(V)$ with minimal polynomial $\mu_T = p q$ where $p, q$ are coprime, non-constant polynomials.  Is $(\mathrm{Ker}\:T)^\perp$ the only $T$-invariant complement of $\mathrm{Ker}\:T$?